# How to access depth (z) buffer data of a render result from python

Tags: python

My issue is that I want to access the buffer data from python, pixel after pixel, for being able to use it for arbitrary computations. How can I achieve this?

(Please dont tell me about exporting to different kinds of formats like exr etc, because I want to do computations  in place).

Also I'm talking about blender 2.68 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

[Image.pixel](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.Image.html?highlight=pixels#bpy.types.Image.pixels) is not available for Render Results, nor does it contain depth-information.

You can get the depth in Node Compositor / Cycles, but I don't believe it's possible to read with python in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can use this trick to get the rendered pixels:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23309/13212

However, instead of connecting the *image* output of the *Render Layers* to the *Viewer*'s *Image* input, you can connect the *Z* output of the *Render Layers*. This will give you the depth pixels for each pixel four times (in each color channel)