# How to calculate the rendered Blender freestyle stroke coordinates

Tags: python, rendering, coordinates, freestyle

[image]Is there any way we can access the coordinates of the rendered stroke as we can access for e.g Cube mesh.

Since we can see if we enable blender freestyle rendering, it does the stroke rendering based on the option selected Edge Type: Silhouette, Border. Can someone please help me out how can we access those coordinates. Its look like blender does calculate those points before the stroke rendering. Please guide me on this. I have followed the link:

[Mesh silhouette as a polygon or pixels surrounded by the silhouette on the rendered image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/mesh-silhouette-as-a-polygon-or-pixels-surrounded-by-the-silhouette-on-the-rende)

still I am not getting the coordinates on the console as mention in the link.

I have attached the stroke rendered image of cube, I need the coordinates of black stroke creating the silhouette shape.

Please guide me if I missed something.

Comment: Since it's a post processing effect I don't know if it's possible. Maybe you ought to explore the new Line Art modifier which pretty much does the same thing ?

Comment: @Gorgious, Thanks for the update, I am still learning. will update here in case I find something..

Comment: @Gorgious, here are some references, [link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/python.html), [link](https://blendernpr.org/scripting-freestyle-shaders/)

Comment: Ooh nice didn't know you could access this data from python