# Getting numpy array of a rendered image

Tags: python, rendering

I am trying to communicate the output of a rendered image to another process. How I am typically familiar with rendering images is to call:

```
bpy.ops.render.render()
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to not write the image to the disc and simply get a numpy array of the output.

This is a somewhat specific question, but I would appreciate any help!

Comment: related.. and still the same answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/how-to-access-render-result-pixels-from-python-script

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot add that I am running the process in the background. The work around suggested there only applies when blender GUI mode is on.

Comment: multiple answers are given, the others all mean saving the file to disk then re-importing ( all easy to do via a script ) then read the pixels. Presently there is no way to get pixels directly from the 'unsaved' render result. -- exactly _why_ this limitation exists isn't clear to me. (simply unimplemented?)

Comment: Ok fair enough, this seems like a pretty expensive limitation for my application. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you might ask about this feature here:  http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-funboard  --- it might be an arbitrary limitation with a simple solution. worth asking about

Comment: I just noticed this : "  The work around suggested there only applies when blender GUI mode is on  " really? that surprises me. got any code to show?