# How to export all X ,Y, Z data from the image editor

Tags: export, image

In the image editor of a rendered scene, I can see all Z values for each X AND Y pixel position in the image when I right click and select every pixel.

How do I export all pixels X,Y,Z values to a csv or some kind of text?

To have every pixel(x,z) listed with its z value

1017, 447, 10.107 (image example)
.................
................
...............

[image]

Comment: An image is a fancy container for an array of pixels, so you just need to load a module that can read image formats. You can also do it in Blender. This might help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/how-to-access-render-result-pixels-from-python-script/82836

Comment: Ups sorry, I didn't see you were looking to get the X Y Z values. I don't know how to access that information, but it might be contained somewhere in the image object since you can access it easily there

Comment: @Gorgious the Z value is just the depth output from a Z-pass, so you could render that and use any color channel you wanted.