# Render to a Python list

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, saving

I'm trying to get my renders to output to a python list or NumPy array. Currently, I'm doing this by rendering the image to disk (with a script), then using a separate python script to read the image off of disk, which seems like a very slow process. Is there a way I can render directly to a python list without having to save it to disk?

```
import bpy
import sys

import time
import threading
import os



filepath = "C:/yeet/yoink.jpg"

def get_override(area_type, region_type):
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
        if area.type == area_type:             
            for region in area.regions:                 
                if region.type == region_type:                    
                    override = {'area': area, 'region': region} 
                    return override
    #error message if the area or region wasn't found
    raise RuntimeError("Wasn't able to find", region_type," in area ", area_type,
                        "\n Make sure it's open while executing script.")
def rotate_cam():
    #initial loc/rot of camera
    loc=[0,10,0]
    rot=[0,0,0]
    bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=loc,rotation=rot)
    bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.object
    
    #add "track to" constraint so camera points at object named 'Cube'
    constraint = bpy.context.object.constraints.new('TRACK_TO')
    constraint.target = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
    constraint.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
    constraint.up_axis = 'UP_Y'
    print(constraint)
    
    #repeatedly rotate camera around 3D cursor (which is at origin) and render
    bpy.context.scene.cursor.location=[0,0,0]
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
    override = get_override( 'VIEW_3D', 'WINDOW' )

    for i in range(100):
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(override, value=.2, orient_axis="Z")
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = filepath
        
        #Here's where I would like it to render to a python list or numpy array
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rotate_cam()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you please share the current state of your script? BTW: Please take the [tour] to learn about how this site works, thanks.

Comment: @brockmann Yes, apologies. I've edited the post to have my script. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, thanks for adding the code, makes it easier to all of us. You would have to find a reliable way to access the render result, see [How to access Render Result pixels from python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/how-to-access-render-result-pixels-from-python-script), convert that to numpy (if desired) and save that array to an image [How to save a 3 channel numpy array as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600640/how-to-save-a-3-channel-numpy-array-as-image), However, I guess you'll need a a lot of RAM...

Comment: Also consider storing the image to OpenEXR, should make it faster: [What image format encodes the fastest, or at least faster? PNG is too slow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/148231/31447)